# How to check another table's columns and get their values to the other table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

i am struggling over this problem 
Shortly, i have **payments** page. Admin selects the user and course, then he should select course_type,which gets value from **courses** table's three columns(cost_group, cost_minigroup, cost_individual,one of them). If course_type is selected, the cost of course must be 
inserted into payments table(inside course_cost column). So what i have done

Tables:

```
payments{ id,student_id, course_id, course_cost}
courses { id, name,cost_group,cost_minigroup,cost_individual }
```

My **CourseController.php**

```
>  public function get($id){
>         $course = Course::findOrFail($id);
>         return response()->json($course);
>     }
```

Here is my **form.blade.php**

```
<div class="ui selection dropdown">    
  <input type="hidden" name="course_">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
       <div class="default text">Course type</div>
   <div class="menu">
       <div class="item" data-value="course_group">Group</div>                  
       <div class="item" data-value="course_minigroup">Mini Group</div>
       <div class="item" data-value="individual">Individual</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My **PaymentsController**

```
 public function store(){
      $payment = new Payment;
      $payment->student_id = Input::get('student_id');
      $payment->course_id = Input::get('course_id');
      $payment->course_cost = Input::get('course_cost');
      $payment->save();
      return redirect('payment');
        }
```

So here is problem how to get this `course_cost` value out of three columns of courses table. If you know how to solve or any method or advice would be great. Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Do you have something in Input::get('course_cost') ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but no i haven. this is my problem. I need the kind of loop to filter and the get values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better get the values by js.and in your field(drop-down) there should be this code instead

```
<div class="menu">
   <div class="item" data-value="{{$data['course_group']}}">Your call1</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="{{$data['course_minigroup']}}">Your call2</div>
   <div class="item" data-value="{{$data['course_individual']}}">Your call3</div>
</div>
```

And then You should insert some controller code

```
$payment->course_cost = Input::get('course_val');
```

And try this on your .js file

```
$('.course_val').click(function({
$('#course_val').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
alert('Your alert')
}))
```

Comment: let me try, it actually gave me an idea. Thanks four your reply

Comment: Thanks it helped!

Answer (score 1):

On your blade, I see that you named the input as `course_` not so sure since the HTML snippet is incomplete, but it may be the cause of your problem.

Better try to check what are you getting before storing it to anything, try to run `dd(Input::all())` first as a start for debugging.

As for getting the value of the course cost, there is a lot of approach, one is ajax the updating the fields.